# Is there a way to stop a vertical scrollbar from interfering with a horizontally flexed list with a fixed header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

So I've got a list with a header which is implemented roughly like this.

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="heading-1">
    <div class="heading-2">
    <div class="heading-3">
</div>
<div class="list-container">
    <div class="list-element">
        <div class="property-1">
        <div class="property-2">
        <div class="property-3">
    </div>    
    <div class="list-element">
.
.
.
```

So then I flex '.header-container' and 'list-element' horizontally (particularly necessary because we also have a way for users to add and remove headers).

Anyway, it all works fine until '.list-container' needs to scroll vertically. Now there's a scrollbar on the right side of that element and everything re-flexes, but since '.header-container' isn't in there (as it is meant to remain fixed at the top while '.list-container' scrolls), it doesn't change and now the alignment is off between the header and the corresponding properties below.

What I really want is some way to either:

- Have '.header-container' add a margin if 'list-container' needs to scroll (e.g. somehow have a class added if a scrollbar is detected).

or

- Have the scrollbar width either be ignored or always exist (without a scrollbar persisting when not needed).

After much fiddling about, I'm pretty sure there's not a css-only solution to this (though I'd love to hear about it if there is), but JS solutions are definitely on the table if there's a best-practice for this that anyone knows about.

Thanks

Comment: Please post a working code snippet so we have with what to work

Comment: Have you considered: `overflow-x: scroll` or `overflow-x: hidden`? The former will add a scrollbar (placeholder, at least), at all times. Regardless if there's anything to scroll. And the latter will *hide* the scrollbar at all times, even if scrolling is necessary. Does that line up with your question?